# react-native moment retorna dia errado

Tags: react-native, momentjs

Estou usando o Moment em um projeto com React Native.

E uma data em específico ele não retorna o dia correto, todas as outras retorna certo.
Eu coloquei na index.js da aplicação para ver se alguma instância de algum lugar não estava atrapalhando, mas ainda sim ele retorna errado.

```js
import { AppSrc } from './src/containers/App';
import moment from 'moment';

const day = moment('2019-02-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD');
console.log('-> MOMENT -> INDEX', day); // '-> MOMENT -> INDEX', '16'

new AppSrc();
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa esta causando isso?

**UPDATE**

resolvi desta forma

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
import 'moment/locale/pt-br';

moment.tz.setDefault('UTC');
moment.locale('pt-BR');
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que possa ser pelo fato de estar faltado parâmetros quando você passa o "const day". Tente da seguinte forma:

```
const day = moment('2019-02-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).format();
```

Se isso não ajudar a resolver o problema você pode ler sobre isso aqui:

https://medium.com/quick-code/using-moment-js-in-react-native-d1b6ebe226d4

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não funcionou, aparentemente é um problema de timezone